# How to create this type of icing and bite mark?

Tags: modeling

I made the donut already with Array and Simple Deform modifier. The file is 2.4M, somehow it can not be uploaded to blender-exchange.

Thanks for your time!
[image]

Comment: for uploads you can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - follow the instructions there and edit your question afterwards with the link that is provided by that partner site

Comment: You could cut out the bites in the mesh, using the boolean modifier, and create a procedural dough shader.